# Question on uniform boundedness and $L^{\infty}-$boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I feel a bit puzzled about the difference between these two definitions:

- $f$ is uniform bounded if $\vert f(x) \vert \le M\,\forall x$ for some constant $M \gt 0$ independent of $x$.
- $f$ is essential bounded if ${\vert \vert f \vert \vert}_{L^\infty} \equiv\inf\{ C\gt 0: \vert f(x) \vert \le c \;for\;a.e\;x\} \lt \infty$

**Is it true that the first one implies the second one but not vice versa?** If the answer is positive then,the reason is that uniform boundedness implies pointwise boundedness or not? How can I distinguish these two definitions?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: What is definition of **f is uniformly bounded?** And what is **f is bounded?**. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, the  first implies the second one. The converse is not true. Consider
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if } x\in \mathbb Z,\\
0 & \text{ else}.
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $f$ is essentially bounded ($f(x)=0$ for almost all $x$, but not uniformly bounded.